# last character of a string in c++ using n.back() and casting

Tags: c++, string, casting, integer

my input is 12. Why is the output 50?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string n;
   cin>>n;
   cout << (int)n.back();
}
```

Comment: 50 is the correct result.

Comment: `50` is the value of the character `'2'` in ASCII. The string `n` contains the value `{'1', '2'}`.

Comment: `#include <string.h>` is the wrong header to include `std::string`. The correct header is `#include <string>` (no .h). `<string.h>` is a C header for C string functions like `strcmp`.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, but how do you believe `cin>>n,m;` should affect `m` actually?

Comment: What do you expect `cin>>n,m;` to do?

Comment: [What the comma **really** does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)

Comment: Check operator precedence for `,`  m is never touched

Comment: Ok, I've removed the unnecessary m for the code. And thank you now I understand the problems. However, can I use atoi funcion? I know it is <stdlib.h>. Would that work as converting the char/string to an int?

Comment: You could use `atoi`, but it's a really simple function best left in the 1970s. Instead consider using `std:stoi` because it natively understands `std::string`. If that's off the table use `strtol` because it has the ability to catch errors for which `atoi` simply returns 0 and ensure that an entire string that should be a single number has been consumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my input is 12. Why is the output 50?

Because the value that encodes the code unit '2' in the character encoding that is in use on your system happens to be 50.

---

If you wish to print the symbol that the code unit represents, then you must not cast to `int` type, and instead insert a character type:

```
std::cout << n.back();
```

---

If you wish to map a `character` representing '0'..'9' to the corresponding integer value, you can use `character - '0'`. Why this works: Regardless of what value is used to represent the digit '0', subtracting its own value from itself will produce the value 0 because z - z == 0. The other digits work because of the fact that all digits are represented by contiguous values starting with '0'. Hence, '1' will be represented by '0' + 1 and z + 1 - z == 1.